# Label for unido a un input radio

Tags: html, loops, entrada

Deseo que al seleccionar el texto de un `radio button` se asigne o se seleccione el botón correspondiente. La nomenclatura normalmente es que el nombre que le asignemos al `label for` debe ser el equivalente al nombre del `id` del `input`.

**¿Pero... en un caso generado automáticamente debido a una consulta?**

```
Muestro código:
//Si pulsamos el link "Eliminar opinión"...
if(isset($_GET["eliminar"])){
    //Llamamos al método "obtenerOpinionesPorCliente" y le pasamos el parámetro del email del cliente.
    $opiniones = BD::obtenerOpinionesPorCliente($cliente);
    if($opiniones != null){
        echo "<form action='menu_cliente.php?eliminar=1' name='form_a_eliminar' id='form_a_eliminar' method='POST'>";
        $selected = true;
        foreach ($opiniones as $opinion){
            $fecha = new DateTime($opinion["fecha"]);
            $comentario = $fecha->format('d/m/Y')."(".$opinion["idemail"].") - ".$opinion["opinion"]."<br/><br/>"; 
            echo "<input type='radio' name='a_eliminar' value='".$opinion["idopinion"]."' ".($selected?"checked":"").">".$comentario."</input>";
            //COMENTARIO!!! Que ID debo poner... para el label for...
            $selected = false;
        }
        echo "<input type='submit' name='eliminar_opinion' id='eliminar_opinion' value='Eliminar opinión'>";
        echo "</form>";
    }else{
        echo "<h1>¡No existen opiniones!</h1>";
        echo "<img src='imagenes/advertencia.png' height='160px' width='220px' alt='Advertencia'>";
    }
}
```

Comment: no entiendo que quieres exactamente porque como tienes el botón ya funciona. Explica mejor el asunto la descripción no está del todo clara.

Comment: Que al hacer click en el texto del radio button se seleccione el radio correspondiente, esta es la funcionalidad de un <label for="nombre"> cotidiano.

Answer (score 0):

Es sencillo. En este segmento de código:

```
$i=0; // defines un incremental para el id de tus radios
foreach ($opiniones as $opinion){
  $fecha = new DateTime($opinion["fecha"]);
  $comentario = $fecha->format('d/m/Y')."(".$opinion["idemail"].") - ".$opinion["opinion"]."<br/><br/>"; 
  echo "<input id='<?php echo $i; ?>' type='radio' name='a_eliminar' onclick='chequea(<?php echo $i; ?>)' style='cursor:pointer' value='".$opinion["idopinion"]."' ".($selected?"checked":"")."><span>".$comentario."</span>";

  $i++; // incrementas para que el proximo radio tenga un id diferente.
}
```

Como ves en el código anterior con el evento onclick capturas el evento para que al presionar el texto del radio butón en cuestión este quede chequeado mediante la función chequea() la cual contiene lo siguiente:

```
function chequea(radio){
    document.getElementById(radio).checked = true;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en el siguiente snippet:

```js
function chequea(radio){

document.getElementById(radio).checked = true;

}
```

```html
<input id="1" type='radio' name='a_eliminar' value='esto'><span onClick="chequea(1)" style="cursor:pointer">Comentarios1</span><br>
<input id="2" type='radio' name='a_eliminar' value='esto'><span onClick="chequea(2)" style="cursor:pointer">Comentarioss</span><br>
```

Comment: @omaza1990 te ha servido la respuesta? Hace exactamente lo que querías...

Comment: Me sangran los ojos al ver codigo en español

Comment: @Federico no entiendo. Dices las funciones y lo que esta dentro del input en español?